# values are reset to zero

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm doing insert via post, but my class is getting zero values.

The values of the inputs are passed via variable and are displayed correctly, but at the moment of action via post are coming with zero values.

The most interesting thing is if you type inside the input, then the values come correctly.

```
<form method="post">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>SALDO</label>
            <div style="border:1px solid #bbb9b9; border-radius:3px;"></div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalDinheiro" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalDinheiro" name="Caixas.ValorFinalDinheiro"  id="Caixas.ValorFinalDinheiro" class="form-control finalFundo"  disabled="disabled" />

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalCheque" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalCheque" class="form-control finalFundo"  disabled="disabled"/>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalBoleto" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalBoleto" class="form-control finalFundo"  disabled="disabled" />

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalCartao" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalCartao" class="form-control finalFundo"  disabled="disabled" />

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalDeposito" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinalDeposito" class="form-control finalFundo" disabled="disabled"  />

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinal" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Caixas.ValorFinal" class="form-control" style="background-color:#9FF781"   />

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Confirmar o Fechamento do Caixa" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  />
                <a asp-page="Index" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Retorna ao Caixa</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And the controller

```
[BindProperty]
public Caixas Caixas { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var C = _context.Caixas.Find(Caixas.Id);
    C.fechado = true;
    C.DataFinal = DateTime.Now;
    C.HoraFinal = DateTime.Now;
    C.FuncionarioFechamentoId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
    C.ValorFinalDinheiro = Caixas.ValorFinalDinheiro;
    C.ValorFinalCheque = Caixas.ValorFinalCheque;
    C.ValorFinalBoleto = Caixas.ValorFinalBoleto;
    C.ValorFinalCartao = Caixas.ValorFinalCartao;
    C.ValorFinalDeposito = Caixas.ValorFinalDeposito;
    C.ValorFinal = Caixas.ValorFinal;

    C.ValorSaida = Caixas.ValorSaida;

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Comment: Disabled input are not posted with the form. You should use readonly instead

Comment: And don't forget to use your F12 developer tools with the network trace on. If you watch the network trace then it would have been easy to see that the problem wasn't the class but that there was no data sent for those items, forcing the class to use a default for the relevant type.

Comment: Why in the world would you have a form with all disabled controls

Comment: So folks, they are disabled because the data is a sum of values that is passed from another page and the user can not change this data, only to read and confirm if it leaves close the box that is open.

What would be the best way to pass data with input disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, all browsers should not submit the disabled inputs.

Following [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled)

> In this example, the INPUT element is disabled. Therefore, it cannot
>   receive user input nor will its value be submitted with the form.

```
<INPUT disabled name="fred" value="stone">
```

I don't know why you have a form like that. But to overcome this situation, you can add an `<input type="hidden">` element with the same name and same value as the disabled input. And send the value in `POST` request.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. Your idea was great. I'll try and give you the return.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use, the Data Annotation "HttpPost" before your method. Like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: This will only limit the method to POST requests, it has nothing to do with the issue